# Почему js не добавляет в оба класса (diaphanous, field) div`ы с классом cell, а только в последний?

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="diaphanous"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
  </div>
```

```
let field = document.querySelector('.field');
let diaphanous = document.querySelector('.diaphanous');

for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  let b_cell = document.createElement('div');

  field.appendChild(b_cell);
  b_cell.classList.add('cell');

  diaphanous.appendChild(b_cell);
  b_cell.classList.add('cell');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы используете один и тот же элемент. А вы создавайте для каждого блока свой и все заработает.

```js
let diaphanous = document.querySelector('.diaphanous');
let field = document.querySelector('.field');

for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  let a_cell = document.createElement('div');
  let b_cell = document.createElement('div');
  
  a_cell.classList.add('cell');
  diaphanous.appendChild(a_cell);
  
  b_cell.classList.add('cell');
  field.appendChild(b_cell);
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="diaphanous"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Да, я могу так сделать, но ведь b_cell это переменная и по идеи ее можно использовать 2 раза

Comment: Да, но в этой переменной ССЫЛКА на элемент, а не его независимая копия.

Answer (score 0):

> `appendChild` - добавляет элемент в конец списка дочерних элементов родителя. Если элемент уже существует он удаляется из текущего родителя и вставляется заново.

Вам нужно клонировать его, чтобы он не исчезал из первого родительского элемента, куда уже был добавлен. Например так:

```js
let field = document.querySelector('.field'),
 diaphanous = document.querySelector('.diaphanous')

for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
  let b_cell = document.createElement('div');
 
  b_cell.classList.add('cell');  
  field.appendChild(b_cell);
  diaphanous.appendChild(b_cell.cloneNode());
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="diaphanous"></div>
    <div class="field"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вроде так пробовал, но не получалось. Но ваш код помог, спасибо!